# Azure table storage python client return not implement when query the entity

Tags: python, azure-table-storage

I have this code:

```
table_client = TableClient(
        endpoint=AZURE_TABLE_URL, 
        credential=AzureSasCredential(AZURE_TABLE_SAS_TOKEN),
        table_name=AZURE_TABLE_NAME
    )
entities = table_client.get_entity(partition_key=my_partition_key, row_key=my_row_key)
```

which returns

> The requested operation is not implemented on the specified resource

I am sure this sas token is granted with 4 permissions and I can use it with create entity. I saw several similar questions on #c or JS language, and I try to follow but none of them works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71566667/python-getting-results-from-azure-storage-table-with-azure-data-tables?rq=2). Should remove table name from the URL part. Although it works for create entity with that URL.